# Django - How to check if server is running in ASGI or in WSGI mode?

Tags: django, gunicorn, wsgi, django-channels

We are running the same django project in WSGI mode for handling HTTP requests and in ASGI mode for handling WebSockets. For WSGI mode we are using **gunicorn3** server:

```
gunicorn3 --pythonpath . -b 0.0.0.0:8000 chat_bot.wsgi:application
```

For ASGI mode we are using **daphne** server:

```
daphne --root-path . -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 chat_bot.asgi:application
```

How to programatically detect which mode currently is running **GreenUnicorn+WSGI** or **Daphne+ASGI**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility:

Inside of your `wsgi.py` file you can set an environment variable to one value you won't be setting anywhere else:

```
os.environ.setdefault('SERVER_GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 'Web')
```

And then inside of `asgi.py` set it to a different variable:

```
os.environ.setdefault('SERVER_GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 'Asynchronous')
```

Then in other parts of your code, just check against the environment variable:

```
if os.environ.get('SERVER_GATEWAY_INTERFACE') == 'Web':
    # WSGI, do something
else:
    # ASGI, do something else
```

Comment: why an environment variable and not just setting a global python variable in one of the python modules in the project where it makes sense to store this?